# Citing the papers from the same author, but in different years are not in order

Tags: bibtex, natbib

Citing the papers from the same author but in different years are not arranged in the order in the list of reference.

Here is the bib file entry:

```
@article{Patel2015AAQR,  
author = {Patel, P.N. and Kumar, R.},  
doi = {10.4209/aaqr.2015.02.0077},  
issn = {20711409 16808584},  
journal = {Aerosol Air Qual. Res.},  
keywords = {Dust storm,MODIS,Radiative forcing,Volume size distribution},  
number = {5},  
pages = {2082--2093},  
title = {{Estimation of aerosol characteristics and radiative forcing during dust events over Dehradun}},  
volume = {15},  
year = {2015}  
}  

@article{Patel2016AAQR,  
author = {Patel, Piyushkumar N. and Kumar, Raj},  
doi = {10.4209/aaqr.2015.05.0325},  
issn = {16808584},  
journal = {Aerosol Air Qual. Res.},  
keywords = {Aerosol indirect effect,Cloud radiative forcing,Dust,Ice cloud},  
number = {8},  
pages = {1820--1831},  
title = {{Dust Induced Changes in Ice Cloud and Cloud Radiative Forcing over a High Altitude Site}},  
url = {PAtel2016AAQR},  
volume = {16},  
year = {2016}  
}
```

It is citing like (Patel and Kumar 2015, 2016).

References:

Patel, P. N., and Kumar, R. (2016). Dust Induced Changes in Ice Cloud and Cloud Radiative Forcing over a High Altitude Site. Aerosol Air Qual. Res., 16(8):1820–1831.

Patel, P., and Kumar, R. (2015). Estimation of aerosol characteristics and radiative forcing during dust events over Dehradun. Aerosol Air Qual. Res., 15(5):2082–2093.

This arranged a list by alphabetically but for the case of the same author is not appear as per published year. I am using natbib with apalike style. Plese, help me in this.

Thank you

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use? I'm not familiar with one called `apa-like`; did you maybe mean to write `apalike`? Please edit your query to post the contents of the three entries whose ordering in the formatted bibliography you don't agree with. For sure, there's currently a serious lack of coherence between what you posted as the citation call-out -- three separate entries, each with three or more authors (but all with a common first author) -- and the bibliographic entries, which all seem to have just one author. And, please do tell us with which options you load the `natbib` package.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake. I edited my post and I am using apalike style for bibliography with natbib.

Comment: Your edit isn't particularly illuminating: Is "Piyush et al" really how the authors' names are displayed in the formatted bibliography? For sure, that's *not* how the `apalike` bibliography style would go about doing its job. To repeat my earlier statement: Please post the three actual entries from the bib file.

Comment: Now, I revised and post the actual entries from the bib file.

Comment: What you posted is *not* from the bib file!! What you posted is the formatted output -- it is not from the bib file.

Comment: Yah, but I am using Mendeley to prepare my bib file and In that, the list is not in order.

Comment: I didn't ask you post things in any particular order. I asked you to post the actual contents of the bib file. (BibTeX doesn't care about the input ordering either.)

Comment: Depending on the bib style it can be a problem that the author names are not entered in the same way in the two entries.  Also you should enter `P. N.` rather than `P.N.` if using the abbreviated form.

Comment: I think Andrew Swann's comment above pinpoints the problem. Notice that in the output, the first author of the 2016 paper is named "Patel, P. N.", while the 2015 gives only "Patel, P." The rest is probably alphabetical sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an educated guess: The three publications -- each with three or more authors, right? -- share the same first author; however, it is also the case that the remaining authors are not all the same. The `apalike` bibliography style is programmed to sort the bibliographic entries first by the *surnames of all authors*, and not just by the surname of the author listed first, and only then by the year of the publication. Maybe something like this:

```
@misc{p:15,author="P. Piyush and A and D",year=2015}
@misc{p:16,author="P. Piyush and A and C",year=2016}
@misc{p:17,author="P. Piyush and A and B",year=2017}
```

Observe that the `author` fields differ only in the "names" of the third-listed authors. The `apalike` bibliography style will list the `p:17` entry first, and `p:15` last, since "B" precedes "C" which, in turn, precedes "D".

If you want the bibliographic entries sorted only by the surnames of the first-listed authors, you should switch to a bibliography style, specifically, to one that is programmed to do indeed sort only by the surnames of the first-listed authors. I suggest you look into using the `plainnat` bibliography style.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{p:15,author="P. Piyush and A and D",year=2015}
@misc{p:16,author="P. Piyush and A and C",year=2016}
@misc{p:17,author="P. Piyush and A and B",year=2017}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round,sort]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\citep{p:17,p:15,p:16}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: In the meantime, the OP has posted two actual entries from the bib file. Unfortunately, the two particular entries do not actually give rise to the issue the OP says he/she wishes to fix, as the following code demonstrates:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Patel2015AAQR,  
author = {Patel, Piyushkumar N.  and Kumar, Raj},  
doi = {10.4209/aaqr.2015.02.0077},  
issn = {20711409 16808584},  
journal = {Aerosol Air Qual.\ Res.},  
keywords = {Dust storm,MODIS,Radiative forcing,Volume size distribution},  
number = {5},  
pages = {2082--2093},  
title = {{Estimation of aerosol characteristics and radiative forcing during dust events over Dehradun}},  
volume = {15},  
year = {2015}  
}  
@article{Patel2016AAQR,  
author = {Patel, Piyushkumar N. and Kumar, Raj},  
doi = {10.4209/aaqr.2015.05.0325},  
issn = {16808584},  
journal = {Aerosol Air Qual.\ Res.},  
keywords = {Aerosol indirect effect,Cloud radiative forcing,Dust,Ice cloud},  
number = {8},  
pages = {1820--1831},  
title = {{Dust Induced Changes in Ice Cloud and Cloud Radiative Forcing over a High Altitude Site}},  
url = {PAtel2016AAQR},  
volume = {16},  
year = {2016}  
}  
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\citep{Patel2016AAQR,Patel2015AAQR}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind response but this is not working for me. As per the norms, I have to follow apalike style. As well as when I am using sort option with natbib, it sorts the list of references but it is not working when I am citing particular references from the same author (i.e. Patel et al., 2016, 2015).

Comment: @PiyushkumarPatel -- Please, please, please do what I've asked you for several times now: Post the actual contents of the three bib entries from the bib file. *Not* the from the bbl file, but from the bib file. If you can't be bothered to do so, please go ahead and just delete your posting, since quite clearly no correct and usable answer can be generated based solely on the information you've posted so far.

Comment: ok please tell me how I can write the actual entries from bib file in the post. I got those from my bib file but here how can I post?

Comment: @PiyushkumarPatel - Click on the "edit" tag of your own posting. You must have already done so before, since you've managed to edit your posting.

Comment: No, I am asking that how particularly bib file entry I can write it here?

Comment: @PiyushkumarPatel - Sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking. Are you unsure how to direct Mendeley to write the contents of the database to a bib file? If so, please consult Mendeley's help system. I've heard of Mendeley, but I've never used it myself.

Comment: I changed my post and added actual entries from my bib file too. Hope this may help you.

Comment: @PiyushkumarPatel - Thanks for posting two actual entries from the bib file. Unfortunately, these two entries are not good examples, since they do not actually generate the issue you're looking to fix: Using the `apalike` bib style, entry `Patel2015AAQR` will be listed before, not after, `Patel2016AAQR` since the surnames of the authors of the two entries are the same.

Comment: Actually, I imported bibliography from Mendeley directly, as I said before, Now I tried to arranged those as you said in y our previous comments but then too it is not writing in the order, as it has to...

Comment: @PiyushkumarPatel - I've provided an addendum to demonstrate that the two entries you've posted actually get sorted in the way you say you wish to get. Evidently, there's some information you chosen not to release. I don't know what it is, so I can't help you any further.